# How to detect audio file format

Tags: javasound, java

I wanted to know if there any java api that could identify the type of format the audio file is.

I know one way is by extension,but even when the extension is wrong, I should be able to find the type of audio file

Comment: Read metadata of file cause even If u someone changes extension, original extension persist in metadata of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to take a look at the [Java Sound API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html), where you have the AudioSystem static methods:

```
AudioFileFormat format = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(new File("music.mp3"));
```